# Error with my dojo ajax php request

Tags: php, javascript, sql, dojo, indexing

Im trying to use a dojo ajax function to call a PHP file that then returns the contents of a DB table in JSON format.

My function:

```
 var _getWeatherInfo = function(){
     dojo.xhrget({

         url: "PHP/weather.php?ntown=" + _ntown,

         handleAs: "json",
         timeout: 5000,

         load: function(responce, details) {
            _updateWeathertData 
         },          
         error: function(error_msg, details) {
             _handleError(error_msg);
         }
     });
 }
```

My PHP:

```
<?php include('configHome.php'); ?>

<?php
    $ntown = $_GET['ntown'];

    $weather = array();

    $query="SELECT * FROM `weather` WHERE `town` = '$ntown'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

        $weather[] = $row[0];
    } 

    echo json_encode($weather);

    mysql_close();
?>
```

When using this code I am getting an error message saying that "$ntown = $_GET['ntown'];" is an undefined index. I have tried removing the index all together and using an actual value in the select statement (i.e. SELECT * FROM `weather` WHERE `town` = 'Auckland') but all I get back is the value i enter ["Auckland"], and not the 3 other values that are meant to be returned, ["Auckland", "Sunny", "8", "14"].

Any ideas? I can try add more info if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some other issues with your code, but to get to the one you are asking the question about. You have this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $weather[] = $row[0];
}
```

What you are doing is just taking the first value of the row (of which there is probably only one, and just sending that back. This is what you need:

```
$weather = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```